# How to get back a visa stamp in my new passport?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, jamaican-citizens

My visa is valid until 2026, but my passport is completely damaged. I'm applying for a new passport. How do I go about getting my visa print back in my new passport?

Comment: What country issued the visa?

Comment: It was issue in jamaica

Comment: But what country actually issued it?  In other words, what country does it let you travel to?

Comment: I'm now in the United states

Comment: My visa is still valid,  why would I apply for a new visa

Comment: @user62482 If it's damaged, it's no longer valid even if not expired. But like I said, if only the **passport** is damaged, and **not** the visa, then you can use both passports together to enter the US. The New passport will get the entry stamp with a "VIOPP" handwritten note (="**V**isa **I**n **O**ther **P**ass**P**ort")

Comment: Is the page with the photo, name, date of birth etc. legible?

Answer (score 2):

If your **visa** is damaged, then before your next trip to the US, you must apply for a new visa at the US embassy, as damaged visas are not valid.

If only the **passport** is damaged, you can enter the US with your damaged passport with the visa and the new passport **together**. So the visa does **not** need to be put in your new passport.

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=us&SUBSECTION=AI&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> A passenger may enter the USA with a valid visa in an
>     expired passport, provided also holding a valid passport of
>     the same nationality

Answer (score 1):

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html

> My visa was damaged. What should I do?
>
> If your visa has been damaged in any way, you will need to reapply for a new visa at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate abroad.